# React.js loading data from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, console.log

I am trying to take data from server and use it. But I get error like this - "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". As how I understand it is not taking data from server. And also when I am trying to check for data with console.log() nothing is showing in console. And even from other components console.log() except app.js is not working.  I just can't find the problem.... I have this code in react.js :

```
  import  React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    class ProductListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { products : []};
        console.log ('ProductListContainer constructor');
    }

    componentWillMount (){
        var self = this;
        axios.get('https://itpro2017.herokuapp.com/api/products')
        .then ((result) => {
            self.setState({products:result.data});
            console.log(result + ' data');    
        })
        .catch ((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }

render()
{
    return <ProductListContainer products={this.state.products}/>
}
};

      import  React from 'react';
      import ProductCardComponent from 
     '../ProductCardComponent/ProductCardComponent';
       import ProductListContainer from 
      'C:/Users/DoNata/Desktop/JavaTechnologijos/new-shop/src/container/';
      import './ProductListComponent.css';


    var ProductListComponent = function(props) {
     var productCards = props.products.map((product, index) => {
      return (
         <ProductCardComponent
         key={index}
         id={product.id}
        image={product.image}
        title={product.title}
        description={product.description}
        price={product.price}
         />
        );
      });
       return (
      <div className="row">
        {productCards}</div>
       );
    };

     export default ProductListComponent;
```

Comment: You list is never requesting the `ProductListContainer`, so the data is not loaded. Apart from that the data is set in the `ProductListContainer` on this.state, not in `ProductListComponent` on props

Comment: You are rendering `ProductListContainer ` inside the same component, i think you meant `ProductListComponent `

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are a couple of issues. But mainly, you need to return the `ProductListComponent`, not the `ProductListContainer` in the first `render` method (currently you're recursively nesting `ProductListContainer` and then never actually using it). Therefore, you should be importing `ProductListComponent` from within `ProductListContainer`, not the other way around. And as a fail safe, wrap the `map` function in an if statement checking that `props.products` actually has content.

I would also consider renaming some of these components because it's hard to read, but that's not my business.

edit: I believe that if your code looks something like this, it should work. You will have to adjust the import statement at the top of the ProductListContainer file to point to the correct file:

**Container Element**

```
import  React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ProductListComponent from './wherever/this/is/located'

class ProductListContainer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { products : []};
    console.log ('ProductListContainer constructor');
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('https://itpro2017.herokuapp.com/api/products')
      .then ((result) => {
        self.setState({products:result.data});
        console.log(result + ' data');  
      })
      .catch ((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  render () {
    return <ProductListComponent products={this.state.products} />
  }
};
```

**Component Element**

```
import  React from 'react';
import ProductCardComponent from 
'../ProductCardComponent/ProductCardComponent';
import './ProductListComponent.css';


var ProductListComponent = function(props) {
  var productCards
  // check that props.products has anything in it
  if (props.products.length) {
    productCards = props.products.map((product, index) => {
      return (
        <ProductCardComponent
          key={index}
          id={product.id}
          image={product.image}
          title={product.title}
          description={product.description}
          price={product.price} />
      );
    });
  } else { // otherwise, just return an empty div until the server response
           // comes back
    productCards = <div />
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {productCards}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListComponent;
```

Comment: Hi. So I I am trying to fix it. As I understand I need to import ProductListComponent from ProductListContainer to my another ProductListComponent( You were write, I should rename it:D). But know error says that there is duplicate because I imported that ProductListComponent and also have var ProductListComponent. What I am doing wrong?:/ Should I rename that var?

Comment: Let's just break it down a bit: 

You have a Container (ListProductContainer) element and a Component 
(ListProductComponent) Element. The Container needs to import the Component. And the Component needs to allow itself to be exported. You should not be importing something into a file where you are then redefining it. So, yes, rename that var.

Comment: Edited the answer; if it works, please accept it again. If you're still confused about why it works, let me know.

Comment: Hey. I am still struggling. I just checked my code and compare with yours. Everything looks fine. But  it's not working... I imported component to container, change var name, but now it is again saying that can't resolve undefined where I am checking props or mapping. Some time it looks like it should work. App stars to load but that's all. It never done with loading. I can see in console, that container constructor was called and some increasing numbers near. But in browser nothing happens.

Comment: So this is very typical of workflow in React. What it sounds like is that props aren't coming through properly, so we want to ensure what is happening. Drop a console.log in the first line of the Component element with some garbage text ("hello world" will do just fine). If that works, replace "Hello World" with just `props` and see what the Component Element is receiving from its parent. This is something you'll be doing a lot in React. If you're building two components at the same time, you're more likely to make a mistake. Ensure that each one works before the next you move on to the next